# Delphi dynamic SQL in Delphi 7

Tags: sql, delphi, select, dynamic

hello how can i prepare dynamic where in sql 
my form elemants edit1, edit2, edit3 and datetimepicker1, 2

if user cannot select datetimepicker then query must `select * from table`
if user select datetimepicker then buttom question is ok
also user not select edit1 is null and edit2 is null
but select edit3 is selected how is create query

```
adoquery1.close;
adoquery1.sql.clear;
adoquery1.sql.add('where siptar>=');
adoquery1.sql.add(QuotedStr(DateTostr(DateTimePicker1.DateTime)+' 00:00:00.000')+' and siptar <=');
adoquery1.sql.add(QuotedStr(DateTostr(DateTimePicker2.DateTime)+' 23:59:59.000'));
adoquery1.Open;
```

---

i found neccesary code..

```
ADOQuery1.sql.clear;
ADOQuery1.sql.add('select ck.cname, si.rkod, sk.location, sk.sipno, sh.skod, convert(varchar(50), sk.siptar, 105) as siptar from siparis_kay sk');
ADOQuery1.sql.add('left join siparis_har sh on sh.sipno = sk.sipno');
ADOQuery1.sql.add('left join cari_kart ck on ck.ckod = sk.Carikod');
ADOQuery1.sql.add('left join si_gchar si on si.fisno = sh.sipno and si.fisharInx=sh.sipharinx and si.skod = sh.skod');
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('WHERE 1=1' );

If EdtStok.Text <> '' then
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and sh.skod >= ' + QuotedStr(EdtStok.Text));

If EdtStok1.Text <> '' then
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and sh.skod <= ' + QuotedStr(EdtStok1.Text));

If EdtCari.Text <> '' then
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and ck.ckod >= ' + QuotedStr(EdtCari.Text));

If EdtCari1.Text <> '' then
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and ck.ckod <= ' + QuotedStr(EdtCari1.Text));

If EdtLocation.Text  <> '' then
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and sk.location = ' + QuotedStr(EdtLocation.Text));

ADOQuery1.sql.add('and siptar >= ' + QuotedStr(DateTostr(dtpbas.DateTime) + ' 00:00:00.000'));
ADOQuery1.sql.add('and siptar <= ' + QuotedStr(DateTostr(dtpbit.DateTime) + ' 23:59:59.997'));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what's the intention of edit1,edit2,edit3 and where the Main SQL missing in your example should come from. As a sidenote you should use parameters e.g.:`C_DATEWHERE = #13#10'WHERE siptar >= :D1 and siptar < :D2';`

Comment: In addition to Bummi's comments you also need to be careful using DateTimePicker's DateTime value as query parameters. Even though you have mode set to dtkDate, TDateTimePicker returns the current time, so when assigning your parameters you need to Trunc the Fromdate or you'll get different results at different times of the day.